# HashMap, перезаписывается информация

Tags: java

Что хочу: В задаче мне нужна функция поиска объекта Department по его имени, поэтому логично использовать HashMap<String, Department>, в котором в качестве ключа используется имя подразделения, а в качестве объекта – сам объект Department

Проблема: коллекция, при нахождении департамента, с таким же названием, например, "первый", он перезаписывает информацию, а нужно, чтобы добавлял для того, чтобы потом осуществлять поиск по номеру департамента.

Знаю, что ключи должны быть уникальными, но какой тогда выход из этой ситуации может быть, кроме как поменять местами номер департамента и объект класса.

У меня всего 2 департамента, первый и второй.

Моя коллекция:

```
Map<String, Department> DepEmployee = new HashMap<>();
```

Как добавляю информацию:

```
DepEmployee.put(strings[2], dep);
```

Полностью программа:
Главный класс.

```
public class Task implements AutoCloseable{
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{
        HashMap<String, Department> DepEmployee = new HashMap<>();

        String path = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

        assert path != null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")); br) {
            while (true) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                if (Check(line) != null) {
                    String[] strings = line.split("/");
                    Employee emp = new Employee(strings[0], new BigDecimal(strings[1]));
                    Department dep = new Department(strings[2]);
                    DepEmployee.put(strings[2], dep);
                    dep.addEmployee(emp);
                    System.out.println(strings[0] + " " + strings[1] + " " + strings[2] + " - корректна, обрабатываем");
                }
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, Department> entry : DepEmployee.entrySet())
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());

            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println("Выбрали корректные варианты");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Файл не был найден, проверьте путь");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Исправьте путь к файлу, выходите за массив");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы забыли прописать путь к файлу");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
        }
    }

    public static String[] Check(String line) {
        String regex = "[А-Яа-яЁёA-Za-z\\s]+";
        if (!(line = line.trim()).isEmpty()) {
            String[] strings = line.split("/");
            if (strings.length < 3) {
                System.out.println(line + " - неверный формат строки, ожидаем ФИО/10000.12/Департамент");
                return null;
            }
            if (!(strings[0].matches(regex) && strings[2].matches(regex))) {
                System.out.println(line + " - неверный формат ввода, нужно: Буквы/Цифры/Буквы");
                return null;
            }
            if (!strings[1].matches("\\d{5}(\\.\\d{1,2})?")) {
                System.out.println(line + " - некорректный ввод цифр, знаков. Зарплата не может быть отрицательной и иметь меньше 5 знаков");
                return null;
            }
            return strings;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
    }
}
```

Класс с информацией о департаменте

```
public class Department {
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    public Department(String name, List<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }

    public Department(String name) {
        this(name, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return employeeList;
    }

    public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        employeeList.add(emp);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", employeeList=" + employeeList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Класс с информацией о работнике

```
public class Employee {

    private BigDecimal salary;
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name, BigDecimal salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "salary=" + salary +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Файл для парсинга

```
Ситов /13000.1234134/Первый
Курбян -13000.123/Второй
Кошкин 13000.123/Первый
Кошкин/13000.13/Первый
Петрович Котович Кот/13000.13/Первый
43242/13424/Второй
Жестков/13424/43242
Петровна/привет/Второй
Иванович/-10000/Второй
/ 132/ Первый
Петров/10000/Второй
Иванов/0/Второй
Сидоров/20000/Первый

Пушкин/40000/Первый
 Пушкин / 40000   Первый
```

Comment: есть такая штука , которая называется multimap, когда одному ключу соответствует множество значений. в коре такой реализации, к сожалению, нет, однако, она есть в гугловой guava. почитайте про эту реализацию здесь https://www.baeldung.com/guava-multimap

Comment: B `DepEmployee.put(strings[2], (List<Department>) dep);` часть  `(List<Department>) dep` - что делает?

Comment: @Igor, создает лист из одного Department

Comment: @azlov Сомневаюсь :).

Comment: @Igor обновил, добавил как было изначально. Правил в соответствии с тем, как подсказали.

Comment: @Igor, попытка была)

Comment: @Blacit Ответ ниже - правильный. Замените две строчки `Department dep = new Department(strings[2]); DepEmployee.put(strings[2], dep);` на код из ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map, в которой лежат Department

```
Map<String, Department> departments = new HashMap<>();
```

В цикле не нужно каждый раз создавать новый объект Department. Нужно уже в существующий (если есть) класть Employee:

```
 if (Check(line) != null) {    
    String[] strings = line.split("/");
    Employee emp = new Employee(strings[0], new BigDecimal(strings[1]));
    if (!departments.containsKey(string[2])) { // проверяем, существует ли такой департамент
      departments.put(string[2], new Department(strings[2]); //ели нет, то создаем и кладем в мапу
    }
    departments.get(string[2]).addEmployee(emp); // достаем департамент по ключу, и сразу дергаем метод addEmployee (чтобы добавить нового)
 }
```

Comment: Попытался такой вариант сделать, но ничего не поменялось, у меня раньше был такой вывод, остался тем же `Первый - [Department{name='Первый', employeeList=[Employee{salary=40000, name='Пушкин'}]}]
Второй - [Department{name='Второй', employeeList=[Employee{salary=10000, name='Петров'}]}]` . Могу добавить код программы полностью. Верно понимаю, что тогда заполнение будет выглядеть вот так: `DepEmployee.put(strings[2], (List<Department>) dep);`

Comment: @Blacit, добавьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Обновил топик с вашими правками

Comment: @Blacit, обновил ответ

Comment: Я пытаюсь это сделать, перезаписать, но он просто исключение выбрасывает и ничего не делает, nullpointer. Прошёлся отладчиком, во время первого прохода в depList попадает null. А на второй проход не идёт.

Comment: @Blacit, можете показать пример строки из файла, который вы парсите?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111265/discussion-between-blacit-and-azlov).

Comment: `if (!departments.containsKey(string[2])) {`

Comment: @Igor, спасибо, поправил